# How can i add Big Text in Gmail App Script Add In?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create an add-in for Gmail using the app script. I want to use large text on top of the add-in.

But as the documentation says Gmail Add-in only supports CardService as of now, can't render an HTML there. After my research, I didn't find any option through CardService to achieve the same.
But I saw another Google Add-in doing the same I wanted to achieve.

**Google Keep**

[image]

I want something like `No notes yet` text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The [TextParagraph class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-paragraph) supports some [basic HTML formatting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting), but this functionality does not support font size.*

#### Feature Request:

There is however a pre-existing feature request on Google's Issue Tracker requesting this exact functionality. You can see this at the following link:

- [Request for API or function to set font sizes in text paragraphs.](https://issuetracker.google.com/161477080)

I urge you to hit the star on this feature request report, as Google prioritises feature requests based on popularity.

Comment: Already tried the Font tag, the tag works but with a color attribute. The size attribute isn't working.

Comment: @architjn My apologies - it seems you are right. This isn't currently possible, and there is a feature request for it - I have updated my answer to reflect this. Remember that the Keep Gmail add-on is created by Google for the platform so it's possible that they may be able to use more functionality than is currently available to us mere mortals